# Getting error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Cinemas_Cinemas_CinemaId' on table 'Cinemas' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

[update migration screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc9n2.png)
[update migration screen shot cont'd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P86Oo.png)

I am following a Udemy C# course and I am stuck with this error. I tried removing and adding the migration again and it did not work.

Can someone help me fix this issue? Thanks

Error:

> Error. Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Cinemas_Cinemas_CinemaId' on table 'Cinemas' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, and also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, there's an incredible amount of questions on this exception. Please try to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `on DELETE CASCADE` on the same table, that will cause the recursive loop in a table, that's why you got this error if you want to do that, I think you need to do in the application level or use stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

> I am following a Udemy C# course and I am stuck with this error. I
> tried removing and adding the migration again and it did not work.

[image]

Actually, this is officially [a known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). Because Primary keys are mapped by [default convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions). You can't have single collection referenced by two FKs. Projects is mapped without cascading delete because it doesn't work in these self referencing many-to-many. Therefore, We have two ways to handle this scenario thus the error:

**1. Change one or more of the relationships to not cascade delete.**

Depending on your error and scenario, you can make your entity (Cinemas) relationship  optional by giving it a nullable foreign key property: for instance we can do something like:

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);// Or you can try
.IsRequired(false)
```

**Note:** Either of one `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` or `.IsRequired(false)` should resolve your issue. You can check our [official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)

**2. Configure the database without one or more of these cascade deletes,
then ensure all dependent entities are loaded so that EF Core can
perform the cascading behavior.**

Considering this appreach we can keep the `Cinemas`, and `Other Entity` relationship required and configured for cascade delete, but make this configuration only apply to tracked entities, not the database:

**Imaginary Entity Definition:**

As you haven't shared your entity details, so we can assume as following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {

            builder.Entity<Cinemas>()
                .HasOne(p => p.YourEntityDefination)
                .WithMany(b => b.YourEntityDefination)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.YourEntityDefination)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);// Or .IsRequired(false)

            builder.Entity<OtherEntity>()
                .HasOne(p => p.OtherEntityDefination)
                .WithMany(b => b.OtherEntityDefination)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.OtherEntityDefination)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // Or .IsRequired(false)
  }
```

**Note:** As you may know `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);` or `ClientCascade` allows the `DBContext` to delete entities even if there is a `cyclic ref` or `LOCK` on it. Please read more on the [official guideline for more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors) . In addition, as you haven't share your detele operation code while, executing your project make sure you are also removing language [from context like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#when-cascading-behaviors-happen).